# How to build simple image rotation effect like this one in exapmle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know how to build this image tape effect with simple javascript and little css ? :> EXAMPLE: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/56/

Comment: He used this library: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: save page will  give a starting point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the page source, you will see this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/js/jquery.carouFredSel.js"></script>
```

You can also see the javascript(jQuery) code its calling

```
$(function() {
            var _direction = 'left';
            $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                direction: _direction,
                responsive: true,
                circular: false,
                items: {
                    width: 350,
                    height: '100%',
                    visible: {
                        min: 2,
                        max: 5
                    }
                },
                scroll: {
                    items: 1,
                    duration: 1000,
                    timeoutDuration: 500,
                    pauseOnHover: 'immediate',
                    onEnd: function( data ) {
                        _direction = ( _direction == 'left' ) ? 'right' : 'left';
                        $(this).trigger( 'configuration', [ 'direction', _direction ] );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

You will also see the CSS style its applying on the site

```
html, #c-carousel {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #c-carousel {
            min-height: 600px;
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
        }
        #c-carousel * {
            font-family: Arial, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #333;
            line-height: 22px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 150px;
            left: 0;
        }
        #carousel {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #carousel img {
            display: block;
            float: left;
        }

        #source {
            text-align: center;
            width: 400px;
            margin: 0 0 0 -200px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 50%;
        }
        #source, #source a {
            color: #999;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
```